On the dimension of the zero set of a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space.
Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $f\colon H \to \mathbb{C}$ be a linear bounded functional. Since $\ker f$ is a closed vector subspace of $H$ we have that $$H=\ker f\oplus \ (\ker f)^\perp.$$ We suppose that $f\ne 0$, then $\ker f \subset H$ and then for the above relation we deduce that $\{0\}\subset (\ker f )^\perp$.

Can we say anything about $(\ker f)^\perp$ dimension?

I observe that $$(\ker f)^\perp=\{x\in H\;|\; f(x)\ne0\}=:(Z(f))^c$$

Can we what conlude anything on the dimension of the zero set of a bounded linear functional?


That final line of equations is not what $(\text{ker} , f)^\perp$ is - that’s the set-theoretic complement of $\text{ker} , f$, not the orthogonal complement of $\text{ker} , f$. (In particular, you have already observed that $0 \in (\text{ker} , f)^\perp$, but clearly $f(0) = 0$.)

In any case, the dimension is just $1$. The first isomorphism theorem implies$$(\text{ker} , f)^\perp \simeq H/(\text{ker} , f) \simeq f(H) = \mathbb{C}$$

@DavidGaoThanks!But there are still some obscure points. Why $f(H)=\mathbb{C}$, and why $(\ker f )^\perp \simeq H/\ker f?$

For the first one, hint: $f$ is a linear map, so $f(H)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$. What are subspaces of $\mathbb{C}$? Since $f \neq 0$, which choice is the only possible one?

For the second one, just prove that, if $H = K \oplus L$, then the map $\pi: K \to H/L$, $\pi(k) = k + L$ is a linear isomorphism.
